# Пользователи proftpd в ubuntu

Tags: ftp, ubuntu

Есть ubuntu сервер с про фтпд. В `/etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd` есть строчка:    `share:$1$2kOvNsNz$ov/E2j033xsusDDYTwZNE.:33:33::/home/username/share:/bin/false`.
Мне надо создать нового пользователя на папку, чтобы юзер конектился к ней по фтп.

Я правильно понял, что в этом файле надо прописать нового юзера (новую строчку)?

Что значит каждый пункт, разделенный двоеточием?    юзер:пароль:33:33::путь к домашней папке?

Если да, то есть вопросы:

1. Пароль - это его хэш, а что за хэш? на мд5 не похоже,как мне вбить пароль?
2. Что такое 33? Что они значат?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался по мануалу этому: [установка и настройка FTP сервера ProFTPD в Ubuntu](http://linux-teapot.blogspot.com/2010/06/ftp-proftpd-ubuntu.html). Надо было выполнить эту команду:

```
sudo ftpasswd --passwd --name=user --home=/home/ftp --shell=/bin/false --uid=1003 --file /etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd
```

Comment: Разумеется, поставив свои значения

Comment: Правда, что за хэш и что за 33, так и не ясно.

Answer (score 0):

33 - uid, 33 - gid, файлы будут создаваться с таким владельцем. Хэш - это хэш собственно пароля, ftpasswd его сам генерирует.